# LWC: Make a component wait for a child component to load before firing an event?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, component

I have two LWC components - `"A"` and `"B"`. `"A"` is the parent of `"B"`.

On load component `"A"` does certain calculations and queries that are used in `"B"`. I am using a `fireEvent` to pass the result object of those calculations to component `"B"`. My concern is that component `"B"` might not have finished loading by the time component `"A"` fires that event.

Is there a way to make component `"A"` wait for component `"B"` to finish loading before firing the event?

If not what would be a better way of doing this? I am trying to avoid repeating code and db queries.

Comment: Hi @Arthlete, it's hard to answer without the code but LWC was designed for this purpose. There's a binding between attributes passed from the parent to the children. Each time the attribute value on the parent is updated, the value is also updated on the child. To me, there's no need of any event.

Comment: I think you are right, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. The LWC Developer guide is very well done. Don't hesitate to take a look at it ! https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_data_binding